# how angular ui typeahead trigger when focus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [angular-ui typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). How can I trigger the popup items when focus on the input box, not after typing.

Comment: Here is another typeahead module that does it: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##typeaheads

Comment: ...and the question has been asked by others as well: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/759

Comment: And seems to be resolved there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can attest to the issues associated with expanding the UX of the typeahead.  While @ueq's solution works, it has trouble releasing focus/clicking.  I suggest changing things, specifically **how** you trigger the open UX.

#### suggested changes

- *open on double click* - this solves the issue of click-releasing in @ueq's answer
- *check for existing values so as not to overwrite the value* - we don't want to accidentally overwrite existing data when we open, so check first then set to a non-valid value to trigger the open.
- *change the name of the directive.... go with something more descriptive* - considering that ui.bootstrap has already changed their namespace moving from 13.x to 14.x it just makes sense to go with your own name.  Since directives can represent both UI &/or UX, it makes sense to name your directive to something that other developers can later track down more easily.

#### why

When working with a typeahead, people have certain expectations of the UX.  Clicking into an input and having something popup can be somewhat jarring and misdirecting.  A single click or tab-focus into an input traditionally does nothing other than readying the input for keyboard interaction.  A double click generally carries the expectation that something more will happen (e.g. double click a file & close from a select dialog vs. single click to select, then click "ok" to close).

In programming we often try to employ the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) paradigm to our code.  But I think this could be applied also to this particular UX and UX in general.  Let the single-click & tab-focusing do what they've done for years and utilize the double-click to expand the UX of the typeahead.

plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/GGl6X4klzVLKLX62Itbh?p=preview

```
.directive('typeaheadClickOpen', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            triggerFunc = function(evt) {
                var ctrl = elem.controller('ngModel'),
                    prev = ctrl.$modelValue || '';
                if (prev) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue('');
                    $timeout(function() {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(prev);
                    });
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(' ');
                }
            }
            elem.bind('dblclick', triggerFunc);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Editing my answer and changing the name of the directive to `typeaheadClickOpen` wouldn't have made that much of a difference... Or am I missing something?

Comment: the name would not have made a difference functionally speaking I suppose.  But you're triggering something on _click_, if you have an existing value, then you're erasing that value on the model.  Also, in your plunkr, click anywhere outside of the dropdown once you've selected a value and note that the input value changes.  Your _blur_ handler is erasing the value and is unnecessary.

Comment: another reason to rename this @ueq is that not all typeaheads serve data on-demand.  In many cases a typeahead fetches it's data asynchronously, and by using a different directive name, you can ensure that those that are asynch don't get the same treatment.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! +1 :) I'll update my answer as soon as I find time

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same issue and with [this github discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/759)  I was able to figure it out: Setup a directive that calls `$setViewValue` like

```
.directive('typeahead', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(' ' );
            });
            element.bind('blur', function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue('');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and add it to your `input`:

```
<input type="text" [...] typeahead>
```

Result (I created a plkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Si6tFK2AammZy1HqEQzA):

[image]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The problem with this is that when the input field loses focus and the user focuses on the input field again, it doesn't show the old results, but starts a new search.

Comment: you could set the elements value to the last value + `' '`

Answer (score 1):

Use typeahead-min-length="0" if supported by your angular-ui version. Otherwise this will help you out:

```
directive('typeaheadOpenOnFocus', function ($timeout) {
       return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                var vv = ctrl.$viewValue;
                ctrl.$setViewValue(vv ? vv+' ': ' ' );
                $timeout(function(){ctrl.$setViewValue(vv ? vv : '');},10)
            });
        }
    };
})
```

and add typeahead-open-on-focus as attribute to your input element.

This will open the typeahead onfocus if it already has a value too.
And it automatically reverts the viewvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of Boem

You can try this for avoiding the issue of view rendering

```
app.directive('typeahead', function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        element.bind('click', function () {                
            ctrl.$setViewValue('');
            ctrl.$render();
        });
    }
};});
```