# Angular-bootstrap typeahead + ng-click/ng-focus

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-bootstrap

In my app I use [angular-bootstrap typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) component, this way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Start typing to select an object" uib-typeahead="obj as obj.name for obj in objectList | filter:{name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0" />
```

Everything works well, but users feel it is inconvenient to focus & clear the input field to see the full list of suggestions again. So I want to add a feature: clear the input field once user focuses it and show the suggestion list again. But doing it the naive way:

```
<input ... ng-click="selected = null;" />
```

or

```
<input ... ng-focus="selected = null;" />
```

doesn't work - typeahead simply stops working. Is there any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the second answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879773/how-angular-ui-typeahead-trigger-when-focus.

Comment: @Fjut this sort of works - with minor amendments, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution would be to introduce the following directive for that purpose:

```
.directive('resetTypeahead', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('click', function (e) {
          var viewValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
          if (viewValue) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue('');
            ngModel.$render();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

[Demo: plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DsH7ZXTo7Z6azjrpGnMR?p=preview)